# Showing missing information related to a multi-page form in a list view

Tags: multi-step, listview

I have a screen that lists all the automations setup on our application. To setup an automation requires three pieces of information. This is done using a multi-step/ multi-page form.

I would like to show the overall status of the setup in the list view - is section 1 complete, section 2 complete etc... I also want the user to quickly navigate to the section that is not complete.

I was thinking of showing sections 2 and 3 as buttons on the list that displays key information from section 1 and use button colors to indicate if data is complete or not.

Are there better approaches to the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can show a clickable progress bar atop the multi-step form to indicate complete and incomplete sections.
The user can click on any section, out-of-order, to view/complete it.
Something like the screenshot below ([source](https://in.pinterest.com/pin/bootstrap-4-multi-step-form-wizard-with-animated-progressbar--684406474635774511/)).

If you think it won't be clear to the user then you can add a secondary instruction text stating (please rephrase):

> "Click on the incomplete sections to quickly navigate and complete
> them"

Additionally, you can also replace the icons in the progress indicator below with check marks and question marks to indicate complete and pending section respectively.

[image]